# Why is ffmpeg-python throwing a codec error here?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying out ffmpeg-python for the first time and I'm hitting what looks like a complex error surprisingly early on.

Here's my complete code as it stands:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import ffmpeg

sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfile()
targetFile = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()

stream = ffmpeg.input(sourceFile, ss=0, format='mov')
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, targetFile, format='mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

In my head, this ought to be simple. The user browses to an existing MOV file (a standard h264 file which 'normal' FFmpeg.exe can handle no problem on a Windows command line), then selects an output file for an MP4 to be saved, then FFmpeg is called and an MP4 file is converted from the MOV.

However, regardless of what source file I choose, I am always hitting this error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_ffmpeg.py", line 85, in output
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 285, in run_async
    args, stdin=stdin_stream, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 41: character maps to <undefined>
```

The position number changes depending on the file but the error is always **'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position [x]: character maps to < undefined >**

Please can somebody point me to where I may be going wrong on this one? I feel the answer is staring me in the face but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the filenames are generated by the askopenfile() and asksaveasfilename() methods of tkinter.filedialog, and I'm browsing to legitimate file paths on network and local Windows drives. Maybe I need to sanitise the input somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end the problem wasn't UTF-8 or cp1252, and my Python project was already set correctly for that. I've posted my own answer to the question just now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who finds this post in the future- I found my answer, it was indeed staring me in the face.

The third line of the code should have been `sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfile().name`- I had missed out the `.name()` part and was trying to feed FFmpeg an object returned by filedialog, rather than specifically the filename. Once I realised that, I was able to get on.

(I ran immediately into other problems with FFmpeg not finding its own library files and things like that, but that's a story for another post.)